# Does my client need a developer account to submit the app I made them to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval, app-store

I wonder if someone could offer insight here:

I work for an independent multimedia firm who builds communications material for their clients. We're currently working through our first iPhone app. So, my shop has now completed an app that conforms to our client's brand, and we wish to deploy this app to the App Store on behalf of our client. Looking over Apple's documentation, everything seems to be written on the assumption that you are releasing your own app... therefore, the Apple documentation seems to start one step ahead of where I need it to.

So, as a multimedia production firm, I have set up a developer account for my company that I have been using to develop our client's app. However, I assume my account cannot release my client's application, given that it would cite my company's name as the publisher. Therefore, how do I start this process on behalf of my client? Will they first need their own $99 developer account to publish with, or is there a separate publisher identity that I can set up within my account that represents my client?

Any and all help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I typically have the client create their own account. From there most clients will provide me access to their admin account so I can go through the rest of the steps.

I often submit apps through their admin account, however, a team member is an option if the client is not interested to provide admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks @John. I had this question too. When I asked it a couple days ago at the Apple developer forum, people were unclear whether a team member can submit an app, or only an admin. You're saying you know that a team member has that level of permission?

Comment: "There are three roles available: Team Agent, Team Admin, and Team Member. Only the Team Agent has the ability to submit apps. Designating a person to be a Team Admin is common to handle the tasks you described." --http://ios.phonesdevelopers.com/79_13142828/